# How to have Vue handle events for jQuery dynamically created button?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I'm creating action buttons for each row of a table with jQuery `$.each()` method. Every button has `v-on:click="delete"` event handling. But this event isn't handling when click on these buttons.

Anyway event is working with DOM elements from stratch. What's wrong?

Comment: *I'm creating action buttons for each row of a table with jQuery $.each() method.*  That's wrong. Use Vue's `v-for` instead. Don't modify the Vue template HTML using jQuery.

Comment: @connexo yes, you're right! I found the way to use Vue's `v-for` instead of jQuery's `$.each()`

Answer (score -1):

You are generating dynamic elements, so try below code:

```
$('your-parent-element').on('click', 'button', function(){
//write you code here.
})
```

"Anyway event is working with DOM elements from stratch. What's wrong" 
 - check your console panel of browser if is there any error.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: This completely misses the problem.